# Cannot mimic performance of ConcurrentStack when using same code implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ilspy

I am learning about writing concurrent data structures and looking at the **ConcurrentStack** implementation as a learning exercise. As a starting point I have created a copy of the ConcurrentStack implementation by using **IlSpy** to decompile it into C#. I have limited myself to investigating and using just the Push and TryPop methods for the time being.

But my implementation is significantly slower than using the original.

My testing uses 4 threads (on a single socket, 4 core CPU) with thread affinity for each thread against a different core. Each thread performs 1,000,000 loops and each loop does three pushes and three pops. Running the testing many times the average time to complete all the threads is...

- ConcurrentStack => 445ms
- Clone of Push/TryPop => 670ms

So even though the code, as far as I can tell, is identical between the two the clone is about 50% slower. I run the testing 500 times in a run and take the average over all the runs. So I do not believe the issue is the initial JIT'ing of the code.

Any ideas why a copy of the methods would be so much slower?

**C# Implementation**

(For the sake of completeness I have provided the C# console app code that can be used to replicate the result. For anyone interesting in seeing if they get the same result as me.)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int processors = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Console.WriteLine("Processors: {0}", processors);

        List<Type> runnersT = new List<Type>() { typeof(ThreadRunnerConcurrent), 
                                                 typeof(ThreadRunnerCASStack)};
        int cycles = 500;
        foreach (Type runnerT in runnersT)
        {
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
            {
                // Create a thread runner per processor
                List<ThreadRunner> runners = new List<ThreadRunner>();
                for (int j = 0; j < processors; j++)
                {
                    ThreadRunner runner = Activator.CreateInstance(runnerT) as ThreadRunner;
                    runner.Processor = j;
                    runners.Add(runner);
                }

                // Start each runner going
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                runners.ForEach((r) => r.Start());

                // Wait for all the runners to exit
                runners.ForEach((r) => r.Join());
                runners.ForEach((r) => r.Check());
                sw.Stop();

                total += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Average: {1}ms", runnerT.Name, (total / cycles));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

abstract class ThreadRunner
{
    private int _processor;
    private Thread _thread;

    public ThreadRunner()
    {
    }

    public int Processor
    {
        get { return _processor; }
        set { _processor = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Run));
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Join()
    {
        _thread.Join();
    }

    public abstract void Check();

    protected abstract void Run(int cycles);

    private void Run(object param)
    {
        SetAffinity();
        Run(1000000);
    }

    private void SetAffinity()
    {
        #pragma warning disable 618
        int osThreadId = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId();
        #pragma warning restore 618

        // Set the thread's processor affinity
        ProcessThread thread = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>().Where(t => t.Id == osThreadId).Single();
        thread.ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1L << Processor);
    }
}

class ThreadRunnerConcurrent : ThreadRunner
{
    private static ConcurrentStack<int> _stack = new ConcurrentStack<int>();

    protected override void Run(int cycles)
    {
        int ret;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            _stack.Push(i);
            _stack.Push(i);
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
            _stack.Push(i);
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
        }
    }

    public override void Check()
    {
        if (_stack.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadRunnerConcurrent has entries!");
    }
}

class ThreadRunnerCASStack : ThreadRunner
{
    private static CASStack<int> _stack = new CASStack<int>();

    protected override void Run(int cycles)
    {
        int ret;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            _stack.Push(i);
            _stack.Push(i);
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
            _stack.Push(i);
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
            while (!_stack.TryPop(out ret)) ;
        }
    }

    public override void Check()
    {
        if (_stack.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadRunnerCASStack has entries!");
    }
}

class CASStack<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        internal readonly T m_value;
        internal CASStack<T>.Node m_next;
        internal Node(T value)
        {
            this.m_value = value;
            this.m_next = null;
        }
    }

    private volatile CASStack<T>.Node m_head;

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        CASStack<T>.Node node = new CASStack<T>.Node(item);
        node.m_next = this.m_head;

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<CASStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, node, node.m_next) == node.m_next)
            return;

        PushCore(node, node);
    }

    private void PushCore(Node head, Node tail)
    {
        SpinWait spinWait = default(SpinWait);

        do
        {
            spinWait.SpinOnce();
            tail.m_next = this.m_head;
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange<CASStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, head, tail.m_next) != tail.m_next);
    }

    public bool TryPop(out T result)
    {
        CASStack<T>.Node head = this.m_head;

        if (head == null)
        {
            result = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<CASStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, head.m_next, head) == head)
        {
            result = head.m_value;
            return true;
        }

        return TryPopCore(out result);
    }

    private bool TryPopCore(out T result)
    {
        CASStack<T>.Node node;
        if (TryPopCore(1, out node) == 1)
        {
            result = node.m_value;
            return true;
        }
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    private int TryPopCore(int count, out CASStack<T>.Node poppedHead)
    {
        SpinWait spinWait = default(SpinWait);
        int num = 1;
        Random random = new Random(Environment.TickCount & 2147483647);
        CASStack<T>.Node head;
        int num2;
        while (true)
        {
            head = this.m_head;
            if (head == null)
                break;

            CASStack<T>.Node node = head;
            num2 = 1;
            while (num2 < count && node.m_next != null)
            {
                node = node.m_next;
                num2++;
            }

            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange<CASStack<T>.Node>(ref this.m_head, node.m_next, head) == head)
                goto Block_5;

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                spinWait.SpinOnce();

            num = (spinWait.NextSpinWillYield ? random.Next(1, 8) : (num * 2));
        }
        poppedHead = null;
        return 0;
    Block_5:
        poppedHead = head;
        return num2;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: stupid question, but did you compile for Release?

Comment: Good point. That improves things. Now the clone is taking 550ms which is ~30% slower instead of ~50% slower.

Comment: I think, IlSpy decompiled code differ from original. If you try to decompile with another tool (for example R#), you will see, that code will differ from ILSpy

Comment: Use the [actual](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) source code for the type, not some tools best guess at what it might be.  Decompilers are debugging tools, not ways of flawlessly recreating source code, treat them as such.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I changed my code to be exactly the same as the original source code and it still has the same slowdown.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. `CASStack<T>` does not implement a property `Count`, yet it is referenced via `ThreadRunnerCASStack.Check()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ConcurrentStack<T>` has one advantage that your `CASStack<T>` doesn't have, even though the code for both is identical.

`ConcurrentStack<T>` has an [ngen'd native image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) installed on your computer that was compiled when you installed your .Net framework install. Your `CASStack<T>` is being compiled via JIT, and because JIT has to be fast, it does not perform as many optimizations as the AOT compiler in ngen.

I tested your code on my computer. Without ngen'ing your image, I got these results:

```
Processors: 4
ThreadRunnerConcurrent Average: 764ms
ThreadRunnerCASStack Average: 948ms
Finished
```

After ngening:

```
Processors: 4
ThreadRunnerConcurrent Average: 778ms
ThreadRunnerCASStack Average: 742ms
Finished
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like ngen has bigger impact than I would have though.